# How do I make it so my bot remembers what is said to it after I shut it off? I use discord.js for the bot

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

my friend and I made a bot that generates messages based off what you said to it. A small issue though, it doesn't remember anything you said to it after I turn it off and back on. Here's my code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { Client, Intents, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING],
});
const TOKEN = ""
const fetch = import('node-fetch')

const possibleAnswers = ['Im sad :(', 'Im annoyed', 'Im happy!','Im okay']

const possibleMeals = ["Eat some fruit!","Eat some icecream!","Eat a salad!","Eat some spahgetti!","Go out to a restaurant of your choice"

const possibleGreetings =["Hi","Hello","What is up?","Wassup","Greetings!"]

const possibleCodeInfo = ["Arrays indexes start at 0 in most languages, but some start at 1, like Julia!", 
"Else if statements allow for mutliple conditions!",
"Many AI's require a database during its creation!",
"Lua is a frontend and backend language!",
"C# is 22 years old!",
"People used to use punchcards to code!",
"Objects store data in properties!",
"React allows you to write javascript in HTML!",
"HTML is not a coding language, its a markup language!",
"Unity uses C# for its engine!"]

let chain = {}
  function generateChain(str){
    const textArr = str.split(' ')
    let x = textArr.indexOf("<@998859763385389137>") 
    if (x != -1) textArr.splice(x, 1)

    for (let i = 0; i < textArr.length; i++) {
      let word = textArr[i].toLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]/, "") 
      if (!chain[word]) chain[word] = []
      if (textArr[i + 1]) chain[word].push(textArr[i + 1].toLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]/, ""))
    }
}

function generateSentence(chain){
    const words = Object.keys(chain)
    let word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
    let output = ''

    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    output += word + ' '
    word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
    if (!word || !chain.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
    word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)]
    }
    }

    return output
}

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)

  // slash command stuff
  const guildId = '847395379019513876'
  const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
  let commands

  if (guild) {
    commands = guild.commands
  } else {
    commands = client.application?.commands
  }
})

client.on("message", msg => {
  if (msg.mentions.users.first() == client.user) {
    generateChain(msg.content)
    msg.reply(generateSentence(chain))
  }
  switch (msg.content){
    case('how are you?'):
    msg.reply(possibleAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random()*possibleAnswers.length)]);
    break;
    case('what should i eat?'):
    msg.reply(possibleMeals[Math.floor(Math.random()*possibleMeals.length)]);
    break;
    case('hi'):
    msg.reply(possibleGreetings[Math.floor(Math.random()*possibleGreetings.length)]);
    break;
    case('tell me a code fact'):
    msg.reply(possibleCodeInfo[Math.floor(Math.random()*possibleCodeInfo.length)]);
    break;
    //end
    break;
  } 
  
})

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if(!interaction.isCommand()) return;
}) 

client.login(TOKEN)
```

I tried to add node i/o but the command did not work. Did I mess up on a step or is there something completely different I need to do?

Comment: What do you mean with "I tried to add node i/o but the command did not work."? There's nothing in your code that seems to save or load anything.

Comment: @AKX i removed it because it broke the bot when added.

Answer (score 0):

Bots do not save data after a restart, you need to either save it to a JSON file or create a database.

I personally recommend a database over a JSON file, for example MongoDB, as it may come in handy for your future commands.

To create a MongoDB database follow the steps here:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/getting-started/